# How to add SKSpriteNode from a method into another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, class, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a SKSpriteNode one class to another class `MainMenu` which is a **subclass of SKScene**. The class I created `DumpTruckFramework` that defines these methods is a **subclass of SKSpriteNode** (Which may be the problem?). Below is all the code I am using:

```
#DumpTruckFramework.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface DumpTruckFramework : SKSpriteNode

-(void)createDumpTruckMainBody;

@end

#DumpTruckFramework.m

#import "DumpTruckFramework.h"

@implementation DumpTruckFramework

-(SKNode*)setupDumpTruckMainBody{

    SKSpriteNode *mainBody = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Dump_Truck_Main_Body.png"];

    mainBody.name = @"";
    mainBody.scale = 0.5;
    mainBody.position = CGPointMake(300, 400);

    return mainBody;
}

-(void)createDumpTruckMainBody{

    SKNode *mainBody = [self setupDumpTruckMainBody];

    [self addChild:mainBody];

}

@end
```

Above is the method I use in the `MainMenu` class to add the `mainBody` sprite. Maybe the issue could be the `[self addChild:mainBody];` code line as self is referring to the `DumpTruckFramework` class?

```
#MainMenu.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MainMenu : SKScene

@end

#MainMenu.m

#import "MainMenu.h"
#import "DumpTruckFramework.h"

@implementation MainMenu

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){

        //[self createMainMenuTitle];

        DumpTruckFramework *dumpTruck = [[DumpTruckFramework alloc] init];

        [dumpTruck createDumpTruckMainBody];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Now what I think is happening is that the method does work but doesn't do what is expected. As the `MainMenu` scene is what is meant to be displaying the nodes, it's declared to be the "view-able scene".

Hopefully someone can help me resolve this issue, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding a sprite node to your scene. You can change `createDumpTruckMainBody` to:

```
-(SKNode*)createDumpTruckMainBody{

    SKNode *mainBody = [self setupDumpTruckMainBody];

    return mainBody;

}
```

and in your main menu change your code to:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){

        //[self createMainMenuTitle];

        DumpTruckFramework *dumpTruck = [[DumpTruckFramework alloc] init];

        SKNode *node = [dumpTruck createDumpTruckMainBody];

        [self addChild: node];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works Great! Just curious what you are doing here from my understanding you're replacing the `createDumpTruckMainBody` return value name to node and then adding it to the scene? correct me if I'm wrong please i like to get a good bearing in why i need to do something @Greg

Comment: Yes you right I just return the SKNode in createDumpTruckMainBody and I add it to the scene in MainMenu. MainMenu is a subclass of SKScene so when you call addChild: you add node to the scene. In your code you call addChild: on SKSpriteNode subclass which doesn't add the node to the scene so you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dumpTruck to MainScene: `[self addChild: dumpTruck];`.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you are creating an instance of `DumpTruckFramework` which almost immediately goes out-of-scope, and is therefore destroyed:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){
        DumpTruckFramework *dumpTruck = [[DumpTruckFramework alloc] init];
        [dumpTruck createDumpTruckMainBody];
        // dumpTruck destroyed here
    }
    return self;
}
```

So your issue is one of *scope*.  Looks like you need to use an instance variable to maintain the `DumpTruckFramework`.

Comment: and how would I do that @trojanfoe?

Comment: @Mutch95 As I say, add an instance variable to `MainMenu`.

Comment: like so?  `@implementation MainMenu{
    DumpTruckFramework *dumpTruck;
}`